# How to declare boolean inside button click?

Tags: java, android

I want to set something like this on button click:

```
boolean isLightOn = false;
    if(!isLightOn)
    {
        FlashTask.flash.on();
        isLightOn=true;
        return;
    } else {
        FlashTask.flash.off();
        isLightOn=false;
        return;
    }
```

But it's not working...
Thanks advance.

Comment: did you mean flash is not working?

Comment: Declare the variable **outside** the Button click handler

Comment: *But it's not working* is not a valid error

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you want to toggle torch on button click.
Here's how I'd do it
1) Add a onClickListener in main activity. 2) Add isLightOn boolean variable in shared preferences, and handle the flashlight state in lifecycle methods.   3) Add onClick attribute to the button in xml, and declare correct method in MainActivity    4) Add isLightOn boolean variable in the class (MainActivity perhaps) as a private variable to that class.  5) Button will now update that variable according to shared preferences boolean

Comment: what you want to do, where is you clickListener. atleast make question understandable.

Comment: What's `return;` doing?

Comment: @shmosel a very cryptic question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Every time the button is clicked, `boolean isLightOn = false;` is called and `isLightOn` will always be false when the button is clicked. You are not preserving the previous state.

To preserve the state, make `isLightOn` as a class variable and remove `boolean isLightOn = false;` from your listener method.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know without seeing all your code. But you could declare a variable as field member, then change it on every button click. 
That's the simpliest way:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   //boolean field member initialized as false by default
   private boolean isLightOn;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

      final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isLightOn){
               FlashTask.flash.off();
            } else{
               FlashTask.flash.on();
            }
            isLightOn = !isLightOn;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need somthing like this.

```
private boolean isLightOn = false; //defined as class variable;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!isLightOn){
            FlashTask.flash.on();
            isLightOn=true;
        }else {
            FlashTask.flash.off();
            isLightOn=false;
        }
    }
});
```

But make sure `isLightOn` is defined outside the listener scope.

Comment: There are no global variables in java :)

Comment: I mean class variable.